# Encode optional string in Elm

Tags: encode, elm

I would like to encode a `Maybe String` to `string` if it has a concrete value, or `null` if it's `Nothing`.

At the moment, I use a helper function `encodeOptionalString myStr` to get the desired effect. I was wondering if there's a more Elm-like way of doing this. I really like the API of [elm-json-decode-pipeline](https://github.com/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline) that allows me to write `Decode.nullable Decode.string` for decoding.

```
encodeOptionalString : Maybe String -> Encode.Value
encodeOptionalString s =
    case s of
        Just s_ ->
            Encode.string s_

        Nothing ->
            Encode.null
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could generalize this into an `encodeNullable` function yourself:

```
encodeNullable : (value -> Encode.Value) -> Maybe value -> Encode.Value
encodeNullable valueEncoder maybeValue =
    case maybeValue of
        Just value ->
            valueEncoder value

        Nothing ->
            Encode.null
```

Or if you want a slightly shorter ad hoc expression:

```
maybeString
|> Maybe.map Encode.string
|> Maybe.withDefault Encode.null
```

Answer (score 4):

The package [elm-community/json-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/latest/Json-Encode-Extra) has exactly the method you desire.

```
maybe : (a -> Value) -> Maybe a -> Value
Encode a Maybe value. If the value is Nothing it will be encoded as null
```